# A [hint] for a tag synonym

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

[query-hints](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-hints) should probably be a synonym of [hints](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hints) (or the other way round?)
But I currently lack the votes to suggest as synonyms.

Comment: In SQL Server, [query hint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) is technically a kind of [hint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187713.aspx). So if one must be a synonym of the other, I would think `hints` should be the parent tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**.

If this answer wins, we'll make [query-hints](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-hints) a synonym of [hints](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hints) and merge.

Update: this has now been done.

Comment: Seems like there is no dissenting opinion.